# SQL error with mysql variables in hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have the following MySQL query which uses variables. The query is being used in an application which uses Hibernate. I have gotten around handling the assignments in hibernate by adding two backslashes as  others have mentioned on stack.

However, when I try to run my application, I receive the following error:

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'PREPARE stmt1 from @sql_max; EXECUTE stmt1' at line 1

My sql query in hibernate is as follows:

```
    private static final String COUNT_INTERQUARTILE_SQL
=  " SET @sql_max \\:=('SELECT ''Max'' AS quartile, max(visit.id) as id " +
   " FROM carecube.visit order by visit.id ');" +
   " PREPARE stmt1 from @sql_max;" +
   " EXECUTE stmt1;";
```

I'm unsure where the error is, o.O, am I missing something obvious? cheers.

EDIT: The statement which invokes the SQL:

```
    @Override
    public List<InterQuartileRange> interQuartileRange() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return this.template.execute(new     HibernateCallback<List<InterQuartileRange>>() {

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        public List<InterQuartileRange> doInHibernate(Session session) throws HibernateException {
            Query query = session.createSQLQuery(COUNT_INTERQUARTILE_SQL);
            return (List<InterQuartileRange>)query.list();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Provide the statement that invokes the SQL.

Comment: I've added that now, cheers Compass.

Comment: It's been a while since I did queries, but I'm pretty sure that's not how you write a plain query for Hibernate. Typically, it'd be either a prepared statement on the Java side or a stored procedure on the SQL side. https://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/how-to-call-store-procedure-in-hibernate/